# how to install ADT16.0.1 pulgin in Eclipse3.5

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

whenever i am trying to install ADT plugin , i am getting below error,

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
not be found. 


 Software being installed: Android Development Tools
16.0.1.v201111031820-219398 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
16.0.1.v201111031820-219398)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools
16.0.1.v201111031820-219398 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
16.0.1.v201111031820-219398) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0'
but it could not be found
```

I am working with window 7.
I have tried with Archive also but still getting same error.

How can i use Android in my eclipse?

What i will do?

Answer (score 0):

1)First Install the ADT15.0.1 plugins but don't delete it & Upgrade to ADT 16.0.0 or ADT 16.0.1

2)Plz go to the SDK Manager.Exe in androidsdkwindows folder see whether it is updated SDK or not if not install once again.

3)See the Android Support v4 jar file installed or not if not installed from the SDK Manager
and configure the library path.

It will Definitely work!!!

Comment: plz give me the link for ADT15.0.1 plugin

Comment: Please Check for Updates in Help & Upgrade it to helios 3.6 and also note Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6) or higher is required for ADT 16.0.1. and ADT 15.0.1 link is removed as a link from the android.developers.com

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with your eclipse installation. With a little bit of googling I found this: http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/missing-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-while-installing-sdk-for-eclipse-3-5-a-28714/